# Using 'Assigned' ID with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transient

I have two entities, **Job** and **Language**, in a many-to-one relationship. The mapping configuration of these entities is as follows:

```
public class JobMap : ClassMap<Job>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Table("\"JOB\"");
        LazyLoad();            
        Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.HiLo("hilo", "hilo_job", "50");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("name").Unique();
        References<Language>(x => x.SourceLanguage, "fk_id_language").Cascade.None();
    }
}

public class LanguageMap : ClassMap<Language>
{
    public LanguageMap()
    {
        Table("\"LANGUAGE\"");
        LazyLoad();                        
        Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Assigned().UnsavedValue(0);            
        Map(x => x.Code).Column("code");
    }
}
```

I use this code to add a job into the database

```
private IServiceOperationResult AddJob(string jobName, Language sourceLanguage)
{    
    try
    {
        ISession session = sessionBuilder.GetSession();
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            job = new Job(jobName, sourceLanguage);
            jobRepository.Add(job);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Error adding job to the DB", e);
        return new StringServiceOperationResult(e);
    }

    return new OkOperationResult();
}
```

The **JobRepository.Add(Job job**) is simple

```
public void Add(Job entity)
{
    SessionBuilder.GetSession().Save(entity);
}
```

The problem is that running this code with NHProfiler on, I can see the following warning before **INSERT** into the **JOB** table:

> WARN: 
>   Unable to determine if en-GB with assigned identifier 47 is transient or detached; querying the database. Use explicit Save() or Update() in session to prevent this.

followed by (unnecessary) **SELECT** from the **LANGUAGE** table to load the **Language** entity with the id 47 (where "en-GB" is a code of a **Job.SourceLanguage** object).

In my case I do not want to ever update, insert or delete a **Language** entity from the database (in situation where it is just referenced from other entities), it is really immutable table, filled with the correct rows all the time. Is there a way to tell NHibernate to just take the **Language** from me and when inserting into the **JOB** table, to use its **Id** property and not care whether it is present in the database or not?

When I add this line before adding the **Job** to the repository

```
job.SourceLanguage = session.Load<Language>(sourceLanguage.Id);
```

I no longer get the warning nor the **SELECT**, but it is kind of cumbersome to do this everywhere I work with the **Language** entity.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use interceptor class! Override OnSave method adding this

```
job.SourceLanguage = session.Load<Language>(sourceLanguage.Id);
```

when the entity is "Job". In this way you don't have to do this query everywhere.

Look here for example:

[Sample NHibernate IInterceptor implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHibernate_IInterceptor.aspx?display=Print)

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like an elegant solution.